# Android studio failed to resolve errors

Tags: android

When I start new project, I get these error messages in messages window under. I hate these messages, I am not being understood solution. I am new to Android Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your `build.gradle`. Try to use this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
}
```

If it stills be showing errors, problally your android SDK aren't installed correctly. Try to install/update them.

Answer (score 0):

Open to Project Structure window. File> Project Structure. 
Select app under Modules section in left pane.
Then select the Dependencies tab. 
Now remove all your dependencies showing as error.

Then add one by one by searching inside the "Choose Library Dependency"    window.(Open this window by clicking on "+" icon on right end of the    Dependencies tab and selecting Library dependency).